# Как создать последовательную анимацию SVG появления четырех полосок

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Последовательная анимация появления четырех полосок должна соответствовать следующему сценарию:

**Сценарий анимации:**

1. Первая верхняя полоса рисуется слева-направо в течение 4 секунд
   2-4 п-п. Точно такая же анимация для остальных 3-х полос, расположенных ниже
2. Полосы исчезают
3. Цикл повторяется

У меня есть код CSS-анимации, которая реализует данный сценарий:

```css
path{
  stroke-dasharray:10;
  stroke-dashoffset:10;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
}
path:nth-child(1){animation:draw1 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(2){animation:draw2 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(3){animation:draw3 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(4){animation:draw4 4s linear infinite}
@keyframes draw1{
  20%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw2{
  20%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  40%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw3{
  40%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  60%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw4{
  60%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  80%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
```

```html
<svg width="220px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 10 11">
  <path d="M0,1  h10" />
  <path d="M0,4  h10" />
  <path d="M0,7  h10" />
  <path d="M0,10 h10" />  
</svg>
```

Как выполнить данный сценарий анимаций средствами SMIL SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Соседний ответ участника @De.Minov полностью выполняет весь сценарий, указанный в вопросе. Однако, на мой взгляд, анимация смотрелась бы немного интереснее, если добавить паузу между 2 и 3 пунктами сценария. Вот, как я увидел такую анимацию.*

**Выполним 1 пункт сценария:**

Учитывая, что мы анимируем простые ровные линии, думаю, совсем не обязательно для них использовать элементы `<path>` ("путь"). Предлагаю использовать элементы `<line>`, определив для них нужные координаты, где: `x1` - начальная точка линии по оси `X`, `x2` - конечная точка линии по оси `X`, а `y1` и `y2` - соответственно начальная и конечная точки линии по оси `Y`.

Изменение координат `x1` и `x2` линии по оси `X` мы и будем использовать в нашей анимации. При этом немного усложним анимацию, слегка отклонившись от сценария:

```html
<svg width="200" height="80">

   <!--Линии-->
   <line id="l1" x1="100" y1="10" x2="100" y2="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l2" x1="100" y1="30" x2="100" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l3" x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l4" x1="100" y1="70" x2="100" y2="70" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />

   <!--Анимация линии 1-->
   <animate href="#l1" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация линии 2-->
   <animate href="#l2" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация линии 3-->
   <animate href="#l3" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация линии 4-->
   <animate href="#l4" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="4s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="4s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

</svg>
```

**Выполним 2 пункт сценария:**

В этом пункте сценария указано, что линии исчезают. Но не говорится о том, каким способом они исчезают, и не указано время их исчезновения. Это если только не учитывать приведенный в вопросе код CSS-анимации, который реализует данный сценарий. Но мы закроем на него глаза и сделаем вид, что его не увидели :)

Так вот, чтобы выполнить этот пункт сценария, можно, как вариант применить свойство, например `opacity`, которое будет скрывать линии. Однако, как мне показалось, такая анимация будет не совсем интересна. Поэтому, мы применим обратную анимацию, которая будет возвращать линии в исходное состояние. При этом в разы уменьшим время выполнения такой анимации для более лучшего эффекта.

В атрибуте `begin` укажем, что выполнение анимации будет после того, когда закончится выполнение последней анимации появления четвертой линии: `begin=an_4_1.end+0.5s`, где `an_4_1` - это `id` анимации увеличения четвертой линии, а `+0.5s` - это пауза, через которую начнется анимация.

```html
<svg width="200" height="80">

   <!--Линии-->
   <line id="l1" x1="100" y1="10" x2="100" y2="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l2" x1="100" y1="30" x2="100" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l3" x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l4" x1="100" y1="70" x2="100" y2="70" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 1-->
   <animate id="an_1_1" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_1_2" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 2-->
   <animate id="an_2_1" href="#l2" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_2_2" href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 3-->
   <animate id="an_3_1" href="#l3" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_3_2" href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 4-->
   <animate id="an_4_1" href="#l4" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="4s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_4_2" href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="4s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация исчезновения линии 1-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+0.5s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+0.5s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация исчезновения линии 2-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+0.8s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+0.8s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация исчезновения линии 3-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+1.1s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+1.1s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация исчезновения линии 4-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+1.4s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+1.4s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

</svg>
```

**Выполним 3 пункт сценария:**

Для того, чтобы выполнить этот пункт сценария, достаточно по аналогии со вторым пунктом сценария также в атрибуте `begin` добавить паузу: `begin=1s;an_1_1.end+5.5s`. Только здесь мы будем указывать `id` не предыдущей анимации, а настоящей, например:

<animate **id="an_1_1"** begin="1s;**an_1_1**.end+5.5s" repeatCount="1"/>

При этом нельзя забывать, что для атрибута `repeatCount` нельзя выставлять значение `indefinite`, иначе анимация будет бесконечной и пауза между анимацией работать не будет.

```html
<svg width="200" height="80">

   <!--Линии-->
   <line id="l1" x1="100" y1="10" x2="100" y2="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l2" x1="100" y1="30" x2="100" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l3" x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l4" x1="100" y1="70" x2="100" y2="70" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 1-->
   <animate id="an_1_1" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="1s;an_1_1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_1_2" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="1s;an_1_1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 2-->
   <animate id="an_2_1" href="#l2" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="2s;an_2_1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_2_2" href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="2s;an_2_2.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 3-->
   <animate id="an_3_1" href="#l3" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="3s;an_3_1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_3_2" href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="3s;an_3_2.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация увеличения линии 4-->
   <animate id="an_4_1" href="#l4" attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" begin="4s;an_4_1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an_4_2" href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="100" to="200" begin="4s;an_4_2.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация уменьшения линии 1-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+0.5s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+0.5s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация уменьшения линии 2-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+0.8s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+0.8s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация уменьшения линии 3-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+1.1s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+1.1s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация уменьшения линии 4-->
   <animate xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x1" from="0" to="100" begin="an_4_1.end+1.4s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="100" begin="an_4_2.end+1.4s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

</svg>
```

*Объемненько так получилось, согласен. Где-то что-то и можно было бы укоротить, но я не всегда задаюсь целью сделать код короче. Для меня всегда важнее, чтобы он работал. Ну как-то так)*

---

**upd/**

Наличие галочки (раз так получилось, что она прилетела ко мне), я считаю, обязывает меня написать ответ и выполнить все пункты сценария, которые указаны в вопросе, не отклоняясь от него. Так и сделаем:

```html
<svg width="200" height="80">

   <!--Линии-->
   <line id="l1" x1="0" y1="10" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l2" x1="0" y1="30" x2="0" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l3" x1="0" y1="50" x2="0" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
   <line id="l4" x1="0" y1="70" x2="0" y2="70" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />

   <!--Анимация появления линий-->
   <animate id="an1" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="0" to="200" begin="1s;an1.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an2" xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="0" to="200" begin="2s;an2.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an3" xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="0" to="200" begin="3s;an3.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="an4" xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="0" to="200" begin="4s;an4.end+5.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

   <!--Анимация исчезновения линий-->
   <animate id="op1" xlink:href="#l1" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="0" begin="an4.end+0.8s" dur="0.001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="op2" xlink:href="#l2" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="0" begin="an4.end+0.8s" dur="0.001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="op3" xlink:href="#l3" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="0" begin="an4.end+0.8s" dur="0.001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
   <animate id="op4" xlink:href="#l4" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="0" begin="an4.end+0.8s" dur="0.001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

</svg>
```

Здесь мы также применяем обратную анимацию для каждого элемента отдельно. Только время выполнения анимации `dur="0.001s"` указываем как можно меньше, что бы линии исчезали практически сразу. И конечно же, добавляем паузы между всеми пунктами сценария, чтобы это смотрелось пропорционально интересно.

Очень жаль, что нельзя применить групповое изменение координат ко всем элементам сразу. Если бы такая возможность была, то мы могли бы все элементы заключить в отдельный тег:

```
   <g id="lines">
   элементы
   </g>
```

и написать только одну анимацию, например:

```
<animate xlink:href="#lines" attributeName="x2" from="200" to="0" .../>
```

Однако, такой возможности, к сожалению, нет.

Comment: самым сложным моментом в реализации сценария было, как убрать замороженный результат предыдущего цикла рисования линий. Одним из способов является запустить повторную анимацию стирания, а затем уже на чистом месте рисовать снова. Вот так и решено в этом вопросе. Ну что ж, замечательно получилось, смотрится эффектно!

Comment: под стиранием замороженного результата предыдущих анимаций я имел ввиду наложение других анимаций и это будет необязательно анимация уменьшения линии. Тут может быть, какая угодно анимация, хоть та же самая анимация, что была в первый раз, но это будет выглядеть не очень красиво.

Comment: я думаю можно, ведь data атрибуты обрабатывает JS и CSS Но все ссылки на объекты, на анимации внутри svg только по id.

Comment: тут надо просто пробовать, у меня нет такой практики работы с data  атрибутами в SVG. Ну вот красивый, короткий финальный  код. Не зря я заставлял себя писать комментарии, хоть и страшно болит голова. Ловишь всё на лету. Именно так и писал с первого комментария, что остатки старых замороженных анимаций стирают новые анимации Кстати, совсем не обязательно писать `repeatCount="1"` Это по умолчанию есть